# Cumulative Sum Of Numbers

Tags: c, sum

I have to find the cumulative sum of numbers without using array.Like If n=3 & k=5 then my answer will go like this n

```
   1+2+3+4+5 (sum of k elements)
+  1+3+6+10+15
+  1+4+10+20+35
(i.e. n times)
```

**n & k ranging from 1 to 10^9**

Here elements from index 2 are cumulative sum from the previous series from index 1 to index x like

second value in second series is 3 which is cumulative sum upto second value in previous series 1+2

third value in second series is 6 which is cumulative sum upto third value in previous series 1+2+3

Similarly third value in third series is 10 which is cumulative sum upto third value in previous series 1+3+6
My approach till know is

```
        //For n==1
        for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        {
            a[i]=i+1;
            sum = sum + a[i]%mod;
        }
        if(n==1)
        {
            printf("%lld\n",sum%mod);
        }
        //For n>1
        else
        {
            res = (n-1)*k;
            for(w=0;w<res;w++)
            {
                f = w%k;
                if(f==0)
                {
                    a[f] = 1;
                    sum = sum + a[f]%mod;
                }
                else
                {
                    a[f] = a[f]+a[f-1];
                    sum = sum + a[f]%mod;
                }
            }
            printf("%lld\n",sum%mod);
        }
```

Here I have used an array storing the series again and again and finding its cumulative sum but here n*k is going too large.

Please help me out in this by suggesting some optimized approach to do so
Finally I have to find the total sum of all these numbers **modulo 1000003** 1+2+3+4+5+1+3+6+10+15+1+4+10+20+35 = 120%1000003 = **120**

Comment: And you want to do this without using arrays?

Comment: Yes as k can be 10^9

Comment: Please, try to use better variable names than `a, b, i, j, k, f...` Or cut your function in some more little others.

Comment: Yes i'll remember this from next time

Comment: If `k` is 10^9, then the cumulative sum is around 5e17 even for `n == 1`.  This is is approaching the representational capability of a 64-bit integer.  I think the computation overflows 64-bit integers for `k` 10^9 and `n ==  2`, and it certainly will do for `n == 3`, so you need to be looking at an arbitrary-precision math library, such as [GNU GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: no I have to give my answer taking mod with 1000003.So that's not the problem

Comment: You really should put it into the question that you need a modulus of the answer.  It makes a difference.

Comment: for **n==1** i have sorted out the solution n*(n+1)/2 but what about the other series

Comment: Also, how large is `n` permitted to be?

Comment: In case it helps, the addends in your sums are binomial coefficients.  Note, too, the symmetry in the pattern of numbers -- compare rows to columns in the sample sum you presented.

Comment: As another hint (and to avoid overflow) - mod(sum(a,b,c),n) == mod(sum(mod(a,n),mod(b,n),mod(c,n)),n)

Comment: Using a bit of algebra `(1+2+...+n) = n * (n + 1) /2 ` - Ditto for the others. Probably do not need the loops in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using recursion since you can't use arrays.  If you need a little more getting started, let me know (this sounds a lot like a test question so I don't think I should just spell out the answer).

Answer (score 0):

I can point out one simple observation like whatever be the set of elements, since you have to take out the modulo finally, if that modulo(M) is prime then repeating the cumulative sum n times (where n> M ) you again land to the original set of numbers for M iterations. Then you have to deal with just the remaining n-M iterations.

view: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figurate_number ]